# Vertical aligning icon with CSS/bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the code I am using:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">View Task
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
               </button>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

See how the green tick is slightly below the "View Task" wording? And below the top of the wording?

How can I make it so the green tick icon is vertically aligned/centred to the "View Task" text?

Comment: provide us your css too...

Comment: what about showing also the CSS and might even create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There's no custom css, just plain bootstrap. (fontawesome for the icon)

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: How does your `btn-circle` styles look like? I'm looking at the [bootstrap source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/dist/css) and I can't find styles for that class.

Comment: I think its icon fonts. from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/check/

Answer (score 0):

Simple add css. But please change margin-top half of button height.

```css
.page-header{
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  }
button{
position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">View Task
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle">
                  <i class="fa fa-check">icon</i>
               </button>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Add `position:relative; top:-7px;` ('top:-7px';example value) to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
.page-header button {
vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Hope this helps!